# combobox is blank

Tags: vb.net

Seems to me that the combobox will only display string values. I have a table column that is integer that I need to be displayed in the combobox for the user to pick.

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select ID From ATable", con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    adap.Fill(ds, "ATable")
    con.Close()

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID"
    comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables("ATable")
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
```

combobox is just blank and I'm thinking it's because my fields are integers and not string. How can I make it display my integer values. EDIT: I needed to put the function in my public sub form initializecomponent()

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. Are you sure you populated the data source correctly (debug and see if any data returns)? Did you try adding strings manually to the combobox to prove it's not a string/integer issue? And if it does care, would it not be trivial to loop through your dataset and convert integers to strings? I'm trying to understand why you are giving up here, when there are at least 3 things you can try to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I didn't put the function in my public sub new initialize component.... wow I'm dumb.

Comment: Try putting the function in your public sub new initialize component.

Comment: yeah I did that and it's working. I don't know how I missed that. the simple stuff is what gets me in coding sometimes.

Comment: I don't know how you missed it either. It's the simple stuff that'll get you in coding sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the function in public sub form after initializecomponent()